# Import an arbitrary object tree into redbeans orm

Tags: php, redbean

When I get a JSON object tree delivered by a client app, I want to store them into my database using the red beans php ORM.

At the moment I'm trying to do it like so

```
$object = json_decode($json);

// since I know that the input should be of class, let's say, "PRODUCT"
// I can handle the data recursivly and store child object as beans
// through red beans

$ProductController = new ProductController();
return $ProductController->_store($object);
```

(ProductController can store an arbitrary object recursivly as beans)

But I'm strunggling with this method from time to time and I'm wondering if I maybe reinvent the wheel at this point.

Could I use the `import` function from redbeans or are there limitations? The docs aren't clear in that point in my oppinion.